# Customize search

Tags: search, advanced-search

I have a document library with over 2000 safety data sheet PDF’s.  The requirement of the users is to search by file name only as the info they need to find quickly is contained in the file name.  Currently all the files are in a file share and being search by Windows search.  Is there a way to setup a search on my SharePoint site to search by file name and show the file name in the results?  I'm looking to mimic the Windows search for this site only.

The current search is showing too many results…

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the search result only to this scope.
Enterprise or basic search center would work fine if you create specific result source / search verticals.
You can look into creating separate Search vertical for the same.

[how-to-add-a-custom-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/12/how-to-add-a-custom-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way when you have an Enterprise Search Center (or one of their search result pages) would be to adjust the query itself to something like this:

[image: Build your query dialog:]

This lets your users search for filenames without the need for you to deal with an additional result source.

I however highly recommend looking at the blog posted by John (this post and all others from Bella Engen). They are very detailed and highly informative!